# RGeo error attempting to create point from lat/lon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, rails-activerecord, postgis, rgeo

I'm writing an app which I am attempting to integrate some general geolocation functionality including saving some lat/lon coordinates as a point in a database. The intention of this is to allow the user to either use their location (provided by device) or a google map marker to choose their coordinates. 
I have succeeded at obtaining the coordinates from the map or device, however I am having trouble now creating a point from them to save into the db.

I've read the documentation and tried adding this code to my to my initializer:

initializer/rgeo.rb

```
require 'rgeo-activerecord' 

RGeo::ActiveRecord::SpatialFactoryStore.instance.tap do |config|
  # By default, use the GEOS implementation for spatial columns.
  config.default = RGeo::Geos.factory_generator

  # But use a geographic implementation for point columns.
  config.register(RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326), geo_type: "point")
end
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter'

gem 'rgeo'

gem 'rgeo-activerecord'
```

Migration:

```
def change
 add_column :monuments, :grid_ref, :point, geographic: true
end
```

**I get this error in the rails console when trying to create a point:**

```
irb(main):004:0> m.grid_ref = "POINT(-122.193963 47.675086)"
ArgumentError: invalid value for Float(): "POINT(-122.193963 47.675086)"
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/oid/point.rb:20:in `Float'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/oid/point.rb:20:in `block in type_cast'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/oid/point.rb:20:in `map'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/oid/point.rb:20:in `type_cast'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/oid/point.rb:18:in `type_cast'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/type/value.rb:23:in `type_cast_from_database'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/type/mutable.rb:5:in `type_cast_from_user'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:100:in `type_cast'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:42:in `original_value'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:37:in `value'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:46:in `value_for_database'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:164:in `store_original_raw_attribute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:93:in `write_attribute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:50:in `__temp__76279646f5275666'
    from (irb):4
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
... 9 levels...
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/application.rb:185:in `block in serve'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I took this approach after reading [this](http://daniel-azuma.com/articles/georails/part-2) demonstration which suggests that the model understands WKT string implicitly, internally converting it to a "point" object.

Comment: Did you end up solving this?  My rails is pretty rusty and I'm having trouble creating a point object as well...  Will post again here if I find a solution...  I've tried some similar solutions to the answer below but haven't found something that works as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.  SRID must be specified, geographic_factory is now spherical_factory, and the point is a method invoked on the spherical factory of the specified SRID.

For the time being, I've implemented the following helper method, which works with rails 4.2.6, postgis and postgresql.

**Please note that the factory takes the longitude parameter first :)**

```
def set_latlon(lat, lng)

  factory = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326)

  # NOTE: this method takes the LNG parameter first!
  self.latlon = factory.point(lng, lat)

end
```

Moving forward, if you are following the same spacial configuration tutorial that I am, you will notice that the row created in this way will fail.  I addressed this by replacing the `:point` column with `:geographic` column.  The migration code is below.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :locations, :latlon # formerly of type :point
    add_column :locations, :latlon, :geography, limit: {:srid=>4326, :type=>"point", :geographic=>true}, null: false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `st_point`, not `point` as the type:

```
add_column :monuments, :grid_ref, :st_point, geographic: true
```

Postgresql added a `point` type, so the type name in the postgis adapter was changed to `st_point`.

See https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter#point-and-polygon-types-with-activerecord-42:

> Prior to version 3, the point and polygon types were supported. In
>   ActiveRecord 4.2, the Postgresql adapter added support for the native
>   Postgresql point and polygon types, which conflict with this adapter's
>   types of the same names. The PostGIS point type must be referenced as
>   st_point, and the PostGIS polygon type must be referenced as
>   st_polygon.